# Japanese character encoding issue for drawing in PDF iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, encoding, c-strings

Iam working in an app that creates pdf with user information. But iam stuck with a japanese word which is not able to draw on pdf. I think that is the encoding issue.

The word is 鷗.

Iam currently using the `NSShiftJISStringEncoding` to convert the `NSString` object to `CString` using the function `cStringUsingEncoding:`.

I tried almost all other encodings defined in the `NSString` doumentation.

```
   NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,
   NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
   NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
   NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
   NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
   NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
   NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
   NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,
   NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
   NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
   NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,
   NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,
   NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,
   NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,
   NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,
   NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,
   NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,
   NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,
   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,
   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,
   NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,
   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,
   NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100,
   NSProprietaryStringEncoding = 65536
```

Any help will be appreciable.